# STR_TO_DATE function return null in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(LEFT(booking_date , 10), '%c/%e/%Y') from mycase
```

The booking_date is my field and contain data like 01-10-2015 Evening ( 3PM - 6PM ).

And i want to first get the date and after that i want to convert that into date type in MySQL.

Comment: And what's your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change `/` to `-` in the `str_to_time` function since your input dates are in the format `01-10-2015`

```
mysql> SELECT STR_TO_DATE(LEFT('01-10-2015 Evening ( 3PM - 6PM )' , 10), '%c-%e-%Y') as d ;
+------------+
| d          |
+------------+
| 2015-01-10 |
+------------+

SELECT STR_TO_DATE(LEFT(booking_date , 10), '%c-%e-%Y') from mycase
```

Comment: its work but when i put booking_date instandof string it will return null

Comment: Well in that case you may have mixed pattern in the column. try using `trim(booking_date)` within the function.

Comment: Hey man it's work now.